# Assignment of value in R

Tags: r

How can I improve the speed of following codes?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(training)){
     score[training[i,1],training[i,2],training[i,4]] = training[i,3] 
  }
```

`Training` is a matrix with four columns. I just want to build an array which the value is `training[i,3]` according the formula above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can index using a matrix. Here is the relevant part of `[`'s documentation:

> > ```
> > A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one
> >  column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then
> >  selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector.
> > ```

So in your case, the `for` loop can be replaced with:

```
score[training[, c(1, 2, 4)]] <- training[, 3]
```